# How to pass data to Bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a table that's populated in an Angular 6 SPA app with elements of my type "quote". I'm using *ngFor to build the table.
Each row contains a button to allow the user to delete that element, but I'd like'd like to offer a confirmation dialog that names that quote element. It should say something like "Do you want to delete "quote.symbol" in "quote.region"?"
To do this I'd like to pass these values to my dialog.
I use a button to open the dialog.
Delete
How do I pass quote.symbol and quote.region to the modal dialog?
Thanks,

Comment: Please show your code, Its hard to help without it.

Comment: <ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
      <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal">Test</button>
  </li>
</ul>

Comment: <div id="testModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Dialog</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="add()">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I guess the comments don't like tabs. This is my crude addition of a button to each line of the list of heros in the Angular demo. The button opens the #testModal dialog box. I'd like to be able to display the name of the hero whose button was pushed, and pass it to a click method.

Comment: I've come up with a solution. The button that targets the modal tag, can also execute a (click) method. I use the click method to save my row parameters in class variables in the typescript behind. Then I can display those varaibles in my dialog and pass them to the procedure that does the work, when the use clicks OK.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution. The button that targets the modal tag, can also execute a (click) method. I use the click method to save my row parameters in class variables in the typescript behind.

Then I can display those variables in my dialog and pass them to the procedure that does the work, from the click method when the use clicks OK in the dialog.